# How to view custom mbeans deployed in websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, java-ee-6, websphere-8, mbeans

I created an enterprise application and deployed it in websphere 8.5.

The enterprise application contains a singleton EJB annotated as startup which will create few mbeans and register it with the mbean server.

I tried to use websphere_home/java/bin/jconsole to view the mbeans. It did show some processes and I connected to all processes but none of the mbeans tab did list my mbeans. Then I did

```
websphere_home/java/bin/jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=path_to_orb_jar;path_to_adminclient_jar;path_to_thin_client;path_to_jconsole_jar; -J-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=path_to_sas_client_props -J-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=path_to_ssl_client_props
```

Then I used service:jmx:iiop://localhost:2809/jndi/JMXConnector, then gave the admin user ID and password.

Then under mbeans tab I was able to see many mbeans except my mbeans. I searched almost all listings but was not able to find my mbeans.

I tried to debug my application if the mbeans are being registered or not.The mbeans are being registered on startup and unregistered on destroy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug in websphere 8.5, but I am able to see my mbeans under a process named com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher .... I was not able to see this process yesterday. I have shutdown my machine and left for the day. I started the server and have run jconsole after I came back today and I can see a new process under which all mbeans are listed.